# write into expression without using if else

Tags: r

Is there a way to write comprehensive expression without using if-else condition for both cases.

Thanks

1. `n` can take value -  0 or 1

```
if (n == 2)
{
  output <- c(0.5, 0.5)
} else
{
  output <- c(1, 0)
}
```

2. generate tibble with x and y, based on value on `n` - 0 or 1

```
library(tidyverse)

N = 1000
if (n == 1)
{
  x <- runif(N/n, min = 0, max = 5)
  y <- runif(N/n, min = 0, max = 5)
  tbl <- tibble(x, y)
} else
{
  x1 <- runif(N/n, min = 0, max = 5)
  y1 <- runif(N/n, min = 5, max = 10)
  
  x2 <- runif(N/n, min = 5, max = 10)
  y2 <- runif(N/n, min = 0, max = 5)
  
  tbl <- tibble(x = c(x1, x2),
                y = c(y1, y2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be more applicable with `switch`

```
f1 <- function(n) {
        n <- deparse(substitute(n))
        switch(n, `2` = c(0.5, 0.5), c(1, 0))

   }


f1(1)
#[1] 1 0
f1(2)
#[1] 0.5 0.5
f1(5)
#[1] 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `if...else ...`, perhaps the code below would be an option:

- Case 1

```
list(c(1, 0), c(0.5, 0.5))[[(n == 2) + 1]]
```

- Case 2

```
list(
  {
    x1 <- runif(N / n, min = 0, max = 5)
    y1 <- runif(N / n, min = 5, max = 10)

    x2 <- runif(N / n, min = 5, max = 10)
    y2 <- runif(N / n, min = 0, max = 5)

    tbl <- tibble(
      x = c(x1, x2),
      y = c(y1, y2)
    )
  },
  {
    x <- runif(N / n, min = 0, max = 5)
    y <- runif(N / n, min = 0, max = 5)
    tbl <- tibble(x, y)
  }
)[[(n == 1) + 1]]
```